# Storyboard NSTabView TabViewItem positioning

Tags: objective-c, macos, storyboard, nstabview

Im on Xcode 8.2, OSX, Objective C

I have a NSWindow instance with a NSTabView in a storyboard. I'd like to change positions of the tabs. It feels like i'm missing something, this HAS to be easy...

[image]

The order in the Screenshot is the order they appear. Dragging doesn't work. I didn't find a position flag either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I misunderstood your question - sorry. In case of pure `NSTabView` dragging and dropping in Interface Builder works just fine for that task, I cannot take exact screenshot (because command key automatically positions views) but you should see a blue line between tabs with a radio button at the left end:

[image]

Go to your storyboard an manually readjusts the outlets from the rightmost button, you can use it multiple times, even if outlet is set for one view controller already. Take a look:[image]

Comment: Ok... needed to reassign. Thought there is an easier way to go. The drag and drop didn't work